# OpenGL Es .obj loader

Tags: android, opengl-es, loader

Hi I am working on a Opengl es Obj loader for android. I can read the file but I am getting something wrong maybe on the indexes. I hope somebody can help me out with this.

SquareRenderer:

```
package book.BouncySquare;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGL10;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;

import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.*;



class SquareRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{

public SquareRenderer(boolean useTranslucentBackground, AssetManager asset){
    
    mTranslucentBackground = useTranslucentBackground;
    
    mSquare = new Modelfile(asset);
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl){
    
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    
    mAngle+=.4;
    
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, (float)((float)Math.sin(mTransY)/2.0f), -7.0f);
    
    gl.glRotatef(mAngle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    
    gl.glRotatef(mAngle, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    
    mSquare.draw(gl);
    
    mTransY += .075f;
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height){
    
    
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    
    float aspectRatio;
    
    float zNear= .1f;
    
    float zFar = 1000;
    
    float fieldOfView= 30.0f/57.3f;
    
    float size;
    
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_NORMALIZE);
    
    aspectRatio = (float) width / height;
    
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    
    size = zNear * (float)(Math.tan((double)(fieldOfView/2.0f)));
    
    
    
    gl.glFrustumf(-size, size, -size/aspectRatio, size/aspectRatio, zNear, zFar);
    
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);

}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config){
    
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
    
    if (mTranslucentBackground){
        
        gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    
    else
    {
        gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    }
    
    //gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    
}

private boolean mTranslucentBackground;
private Modelfile mSquare;
private float mTransY;
private float mAngle;
```

}

Modelfile:

```
package book.BouncySquare;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL11;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class Modelfile {

objfileLoader loader;

int vertextcount=8;

public Modelfile(AssetManager asset){
    try {
        loader= new objfileLoader("cone.obj", asset);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    
    
    
    float[] vertices= loader.vertecisA;

    
    
    byte maxColor= (byte)255;
    
    byte colors[] = {
            
            maxColor, maxColor, 0, maxColor,
            0, maxColor, maxColor,maxColor,
            0, 0, 0, maxColor,
            maxColor, 0, maxColor, maxColor,
            
            maxColor, 0, 0, maxColor,
            0, maxColor, 0, maxColor,
            0, 0, maxColor, maxColor,
            0, 0, 0, maxColor,
            
            maxColor, 0, 0, maxColor,
            0, maxColor, 0, maxColor,
            0, 0, maxColor, maxColor,
            0, 0, 0, maxColor
    };
    
    byte tfan1[] =loader.indexesA;
        

    this.vertextcount= tfan1.length;
    
    byte tfan2[] ={
            7,4,5,
            7,5,6,
            7,6,2,
            7,2,3,
            7,3,0,
            7,0,4
            
    };
    
    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    
    mFVertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    
    mFVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    
    mFVertexBuffer.position(0);
    
    mColorBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length);
    mColorBuffer.put(colors);
    mColorBuffer.position(0);
    
    mTfan1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tfan1.length);
    
    mTfan1.put(tfan1);
    
    mTfan1.position(0);
    
    mTfan2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tfan2.length);
    
    mTfan2.put(tfan2);
    
    mTfan2.position(0);
    
    
}


public void draw(GL10 gl){
    
    
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, mFVertexBuffer);
    
    gl.glColorPointer(4, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, mColorBuffer);
    
    
    gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, vertextcount, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mTfan1);
    //gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 6*3, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mTfan2);
    
//      for(int i =0; i+2<  this.vertextcount; i++){
//gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 8);
//
//
//
//
//
//
//          Log.d("tim", i+""); 
//          
//      }
//      
    
    

    
    
}

private FloatBuffer mFVertexBuffer;

private ByteBuffer mColorBuffer;

private ByteBuffer mTfan1;
private ByteBuffer mTfan2;


}
```

objfileLoader:

```
package book.BouncySquare;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class objfileLoader {
    
    
    public float[] vertecisA;
    
    public byte[] indexesA;

    
    public ArrayList<Float> vertecis= new ArrayList<Float>();
    
    public ArrayList<Byte> indexes= new ArrayList<Byte>();
    
    public objfileLoader(String path, AssetManager asset) throws IOException{
        InputStream file= asset.open("cone.obj");
        
         BufferedReader read= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
         
         String currentLine;
         
         
         while((currentLine= read.readLine())!=null){
             
             if(currentLine.startsWith("v ")){
//               
                vertecis.add( Float.valueOf(currentLine.split(" ")[1]));
//               
               vertecis.add( Float.valueOf(currentLine.split(" ")[2]));
//               
                 vertecis.add( Float.valueOf(currentLine.split(" ")[3]));
//
//
//               
//               
             }
             
             
             if(currentLine.startsWith("f ")){
//               

                 
                 indexes.add( (byte)Integer.parseInt(currentLine.split(" ")[1].split("/")[0]));
//               
                 indexes.add( (byte)Integer.parseInt(currentLine.split(" ")[2].split("/")[0]));
//               
                 indexes.add( (byte)Integer.parseInt(currentLine.split(" ")[3].split("/")[0]));
                 
//               

//               

//
//
//               
//               
             }
             vertecisA= new float[vertecis.size()+3];
             float first=0;
             
             for(int i =0; i<vertecis.size(); i++){
                 
                vertecisA[i]=vertecis.get(i)/3f;
//               if(i==0){
//                    vertecisA[vertecis.size()]=vertecis.get(0)/3;
//                   vertecisA[vertecis.size()+1]=vertecis.get(1)/3;
//                  vertecisA[vertecis.size()+2]=vertecis.get(2)/3;
//
//               }
                 
             }
             
             
            
             
             //int test=2;
             
             //vertecisA[0]=(float)first;
             
             
             
             
         }
         indexesA= new byte[indexes.size()];
         
         for(int i =0; i<indexes.size(); i++){
             
            indexesA[i]=indexes.get(i);
            
         }
         
         ///
         for(int i=0; i<= indexesA.length-3; i+=3){
             Log.d("indexes List: ", i+": "+indexesA[i]+"/"+indexesA[i+1]+"/"+indexesA[i+2]);
             
         }
         
         
        
        
    }

}
```

cone.obj

```
# This file uses centimeters as units for non-parametric coordinates.

v 1.291341 -0.084057 -0.417895
v 1.097171 -0.084057 -0.798975
v 0.794744 -0.084057 -1.101402
v 0.413663 -0.084057 -1.295572
v -0.008767 -0.084057 -1.362478
v -0.431198 -0.084057 -1.295572
v -0.812278 -0.084057 -1.101402
v -1.114705 -0.084057 -0.798975
v -1.308875 -0.084057 -0.417894
v -1.375781 -0.084057 0.004536
v -1.308875 -0.084057 0.426967
v -1.114705 -0.084057 0.808047
v -0.812278 -0.084057 1.110473
v -0.431198 -0.084057 1.304643
v -0.008767 -0.084057 1.371550
v 0.413663 -0.084057 1.304643
v 0.794743 -0.084057 1.110473
v 1.097170 -0.084057 0.808047
v 1.291340 -0.084057 0.426966
v 1.358246 -0.084057 0.004536
v -0.008767 1.805633 0.004536
vt 0.737764 0.172746
vt 0.702254 0.103054
vt 0.646946 0.047746
vt 0.577254 0.012236
vt 0.500000 -0.000000
vt 0.422746 0.012236
vt 0.353054 0.047746
vt 0.297746 0.103054
vt 0.262236 0.172746
vt 0.250000 0.250000
vt 0.262236 0.327254
vt 0.297746 0.396946
vt 0.353054 0.452254
vt 0.422746 0.487764
vt 0.500000 0.500000
vt 0.577254 0.487764
vt 0.646946 0.452254
vt 0.702254 0.396946
vt 0.737764 0.327254
vt 0.750000 0.250000
vt 0.250000 0.500000
vt 0.275000 0.500000
vt 0.300000 0.500000
vt 0.325000 0.500000
vt 0.350000 0.500000
vt 0.375000 0.500000
vt 0.400000 0.500000
vt 0.425000 0.500000
vt 0.450000 0.500000
vt 0.475000 0.500000
vt 0.500000 0.500000
vt 0.525000 0.500000
vt 0.550000 0.500000
vt 0.575000 0.500000
vt 0.600000 0.500000
vt 0.625000 0.500000
vt 0.650000 0.500000
vt 0.675000 0.500000
vt 0.700000 0.500000
vt 0.725000 0.500000
vt 0.750000 0.500000
vt 0.500000 1.000000
f 1/1 20/20 2/2
f 20/20 19/19 2/2
f 19/19 18/18 2/2
f 18/18 17/17 2/2
f 17/17 16/16 2/2
f 16/16 15/15 2/2
f 15/15 14/14 2/2
f 14/14 13/13 2/2
f 13/13 12/12 2/2
f 12/12 11/11 2/2
f 11/11 10/10 2/2
f 10/10 9/9 2/2
f 9/9 8/8 2/2
f 8/8 7/7 2/2
f 7/7 6/6 2/2
f 6/6 5/5 2/2
f 5/5 4/4 2/2
f 4/4 3/3 2/2
f 1/21 2/22 21/42
f 2/22 3/23 21/42
f 3/23 4/24 21/42
f 4/24 5/25 21/42
f 5/25 6/26 21/42
f 6/26 7/27 21/42
f 7/27 8/28 21/42
f 8/28 9/29 21/42
f 9/29 10/30 21/42
f 10/30 11/31 21/42
f 11/31 12/32 21/42
f 12/32 13/33 21/42
f 13/33 14/34 21/42
f 14/34 15/35 21/42
f 15/35 16/36 21/42
f 16/36 17/37 21/42
f 17/37 18/38 21/42
f 18/38 19/39 21/42
f 19/39 20/40 21/42
f 20/40 1/41 21/42
```

---

Thanks Matic Oblak. That worked.I can render a cube a cone but when I push the triangle count things go very wrong. This is what I am getting when I try  to render this sphere the color is intentional:
[image]

Comment: Indices in the obj itself seem to start with 1 instead of 0.. Either reduce each by 1 or offset the vertex buffer by 1. Shouldn't your colour buffer have the same number of elements as your vertex buffer  and you have only 6.

Comment: Thanks so much. That is working great for the cone and the cube but when I try to render an sphere. I can only get half of it to render right.

Comment: That looks a bit more then half.. First try disabling culling if it is enabled at all. A more serious issue might be you have too many indices. If you are using Byte the highest index may only be 255, so either start using Short or break down the object into number of smaller objects.